# How to add sdk 15.6 to Xcode 13.4.1

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to test my iOS app on iOS sdk 15.6 but the current full version of Xcode only lists sdk 15.5 and lower. I submitted my application to apple store and it was declined with the implications that it freezes on launch and it was tested on iPad iOS sdk 15.6. I am using the latest available public Xcode and it does not have the sdk 15.6. I downloaded Xcode 16 beta version but I did not get the error implied. Now I would like to add the sdk to my Xcode because I don't have any physical device for now. Im requesting on how to add sdk iOS 15.6 to my Xcode 13.4.1.

Comment: If you already have Xcode 16, go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Components. There would be a list of simulators and iOS 15.6 Simulator should be downloadable from there.

Comment: Thanks for your response but to my surprise Xcode 16 beta version doesn't have the components tab

Comment: Xcode 16 doesn’t exist, I think you mean Xcode 14 ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Xcode 14 beta with iOS 15.6 and 16.0. Once you open the location you provided, instead of components their is platform. Once you click plus at the bottom, the simulators given are iOS 15.5 and below for install

Comment: I believe the sdk iOS 15.6 is in built but I don't know how to access it to test my app. Thanks once more for your support

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In case is useful for someone, after downloading xcode14 Beta open the app and you will see the xcode icon in the dock. Right button and from device option you will be able to choose IOS 16.0

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion. I wanted to test my app on iOS 15.6. What I could see is 15.5 and 16.0.